# assigning ref, className, and style arguments to React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

First of all, does the `useRef` have higher priority over `className` and `style`?

For example:

```
function Comp() {
  const comp_ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (comp_ref.current) {
      comp_ref.current.className = "local-container";
      comp_ref.current.style.color = "white";
    }
  }, [])

  return <div ref={comp_ref} className="global-container" style={{color: "black"}} ></div>
}
```

During the initial render, the returned `div` will have `class` of "global-container" and style `color: black;`.

However, after the initial render, the returned `div` will always have `class` of "local-container" and style `color: white;`.

First of all, is the above understanding correct?

Comment: In My Opinion Yes your understanding is correct, this is process where React tries to build the DOM, so based on that you re getting your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useRef **does not have higher priority** over className and style.

There are no priorities here. They are different things.

In your example you change the DOM directly **after the render**. This is why it changes the className and style. It depends which one will occur first.

> However, after the initial render, the returned div will always
> have class of "local-container" and style color: white;

This is true only if you do not change again the className or style while rendering. Like using a state:

```
className={counter < 5 ? "global-container": 'new-class'}
```

If initially the counter is less than a 5. First it will be "global-container". Then after your useEffect it will be "local-container". And then when you increment the counter it will become 'new-class'.

Comment: if it does not have priority, then who wins when a conflict occurs?

Comment: it depends on the sequence in which they will occur. First it renders and accepts the className from props. Then after the render is completed, useEffect will be called, and it will change the className. Technically it is impossible a conflict to occur as everything goes in a single threat. Everything depends on the sequence in which they will occur

Comment: If the Virtual Dom has changes, they will be applied to the real DOM. The truth is in the Virtual DOM, You should not change the real DOM directly